# Need to skip Dense Rank in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, dense-rank

I want to generate Dense_Rank on a particular column but I want to provide default Rank on few value but the sequence should not break any suggestion.

[image]

Comment: You should better explain what you want with some sample data and desired result. AND you should do that using text, not pictures. Pictures although might be useful sometime, does not attract programmers especially when they want to recreate the environment and provide tested code.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is:

```
select *, 
  dense_rank() over (order by case when id <> 3 then id end)-1 as Ranking
from test
order by id;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/epc-07fs)

Probably this was what you meant in your comment:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #test 
   create table #test (id int); 
  insert into #test (id) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(4),(5),(6),(7); 
  with mx(id) as
    (select max(id) from #test),
    data(id, idrev) as (select t.id, mx.id - t.id + 1 from #test t, mx)
    select id, 
      dense_rank() over (order by case when id <> 3 then idrev end)-1 as Ranking 
  from data order by id;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/E82vx014)

Comment: Now If I want to create Rank on id desc with same situation

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #test
create table #test (id int);
insert into #test (id) values (1),(2),(3),(4),(4),(5),(6),(7); 
select *, 
  dense_rank() over (order by case when id <> 3 then id end )-1  as Ranking
from #test
order by id ;

Example:
id Ranking
7   1
6   2
5   3
4   4
4   4
3   0
2   5
1   6

Comment: @Sudi, sorry I don't understand. Ask as a new message and clearly define without pictures.

Comment: @Sudi, I am not sure I understood what you are asking right. Check the edit. If not, please ask using text and preferably fiddle.